# How do I set the location of a Tkinter Dialog pop-up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am having trouble having the custom dialog box pop-up open where I'd like. I've played around with `self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x1, x2))` with no success. Ideally, I'd like it to open in the location of the mouse pointer.

The Dialog is called via a menu command:

```
menu = tk.Menu(self.treeDocs, tearoff=0)
menu.add_command(label="Check-In",
                 command=lambda tv=self.treeDocs: self.CheckIn(tv))


def CheckIn(self, tv):
    cd = CalendarDialog(self)
    docDate = cd.result
    if docDate is not None:
        docID = tv.set(self.ident, "ID")
        conn = pyodbc.connect(strConn)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        strSQL = '''INSERT INTO tblDocDates (ID_DOC, ACCESSDATE)
                    VALUES (%s, #%s#)''' % (docID, docDate)
        cursor.execute(strSQL)
        cursor.commit()
```

And here is the class:

```
class CalendarDialog(tk.simpledialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, master, title="Check-In"):
        tk.simpledialog.Dialog.__init__(self, master, title="Check-In")

    def body(self, master):
        self.calendar = tkcalendar.DateEntry(master)
        self.calendar.pack()

    def apply(self):
        self.result = self.calendar.get()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Edit] your question and show how `def CheckIn(self, tv):` is called and explain **what** is `tv`?

Comment: @stovfl Updated w/ the full CheckIn and call (from a menu command). tv is a treeview widget.  Thanks!

Comment: From a `Menu.command` you get no `x/y` cursor position, the closest i can think of are [Tkinter.Menu.yposition-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.yposition-method). Change to `lambda....CheckIn(tv, (x, y))`. Where `x=menu.winfo_x, y=menu.yposition(<index of menu item>)`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: set the location of a Tkinter `Dialog`?

You are using `simpledialog.Dialog` which is **blocking** in `__init__` until it get destroyed.
To place the `Dialog`, using `self.geometry(...`, you have to **hook** into `self.deiconify(...`.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog


class CalendarDialog(simpledialog.Dialog):    
    def __init__(self, master, coord=(0, 0), title=None):
        self.coord = coord
        super().__init__(master, title=title)
        # super() is blocking

    def deiconify(self):
        x, y = self.coord
        self.geometry('{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}'\
            .format(width=200, height=100, x=x, y=y))
        super().deiconify()
```

> **Usage**:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Check-In",
                                 command=lambda x=50, y=self.menubar.yposition(1):
                                 self.CheckIn(x, y))

    def CheckIn(self, x, y):
        coord = self.winfo_rootx() + x, self.winfo_rooty() + y
        cd = CalendarDialog(self, title='Check_In', coord=coord)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***